# How to find random integer between two user input numbers (min, max)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to develop a music production randomization app, and I want to generate a random integer between two values that are user inputs (a minimum and a maximum as set by the user) on the click of the submit button.

I've tried a mix of using the below function where the min/maxBpm id's are the number inputs in the HTML...

```
<tr>
    <td>Min. BPM</td>
    <td><input required type="number" name="minBpm" id="minBpm" />&nbsp;<span id="spnMinBpm"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Max. BPM</td>
    <td><input required type="number" id="maxBpm" />&nbsp;<span id="spnMaxBpm"></span></td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript:

```
var minBpm, maxBpm;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    minBpm = document.getElementById("minBpm").value;
    maxBpm = document.getElementById("maxBpm").value;
    submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");

    $("#submitBtn").click = (function (){
        Math.floor(Math.random() * maxBpm) + minBpm;
    }
```

Comment: Don't get rid of the code you've tried, bring it back. One of the rules for SO is to include code you've tried.

Comment: I reinstated your code. There is no judgment here on code quality, and the code is vitally important to answering the question as it lets answerers know the context you're working under.

Comment: Do you want an HTML and CSS front end for this app?  Do you want a submit button or just an automatic number on keyup?

Comment: @Samathingamajig Yes, that makes sense sorry about that, I just am self conscious especially seeing stuff get immediately downvoted haha

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that makes sense, it's tough to not feel self conscious I guess, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @quantumPuter I am also working on front end, and yes my plan is to add a submit button click for the number call!

Comment: @TylerGettel we've all been there. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is almost there, however it's an odd mix of JS and jQuery. I'd suggest sticking to one or the other.

Syntax issues aside, the main problem you have is that the logic you were using to generate the random number was flawed as it only worked where the minimum value was `1`. You need to amend that to work with any two random integers.

Here's a jQuery implementation:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $minBpm = $('#minBpm');
  let $maxBpm = $('#maxBpm');

  $('.bpm-input').on('input', () => {
    let minBpm = parseInt($minBpm.val(), 10);
    let maxBpm = parseInt($maxBpm.val(), 10);

    if (minBpm && maxBpm) {
      let rndBpm = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxBpm - minBpm + 1) + minBpm);
      console.log(rndBpm);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Min. BPM</td>
    <td>
      <input required type="number" class="bpm-input" name="minBpm" id="minBpm" />
      <span id="spnMinBpm"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Max. BPM</td>
    <td>
      <input required type="number" class="bpm-input" name="maxBpm" id="maxBpm" />
      <span id="spnMaxBpm"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

For reference, here is the same logic using plain JS code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let minBpmEl = document.querySelector('#minBpm');
  let maxBpmEl = document.querySelector('#maxBpm');

  document.querySelectorAll('.bpm-input').forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('input', e => {
      let minBpm = parseInt(minBpmEl.value, 10);
      let maxBpm = parseInt(maxBpmEl.value, 10);

      if (minBpm && maxBpm) {
        let rndBpm = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxBpm - minBpm + 1) + minBpm);
        console.log(rndBpm);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Min. BPM</td>
    <td>
      <input required type="number" class="bpm-input" name="minBpm" id="minBpm" />
      <span id="spnMinBpm"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Max. BPM</td>
    <td>
      <input required type="number" class="bpm-input" name="maxBpm" id="maxBpm" />
      <span id="spnMaxBpm"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

const randomInt = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);